# Type Error when I run angularjs ui calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar

The following is the error message that I got when I tried to run an example of angular ui calendar.

> **TypeError**: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Object.getTokens (app/bower_components/ui-calendar-master/src/calendar.js:87:36)

The following is the order of js file

- "bower_components/JQuery/jquery.js"
- "bower_components/JQueryUI/UI/jquery-ui.js"
- "bower_components/angular/angular.js"
- "bower_components/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"
- "bower_components/ui-calendar-master/src/calendar.js"
- "bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"
- "bower_components/fullcalendar/gcal.js"

How to fix this error? 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the momen.js in your bower configuration.
This is how I've got configured:

```
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min.js"/>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <script src="js/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gcal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calendar.js"></script>
```